# MVC3 Is It Possible to Create Model from Parent Model in Single View/Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc, razor

So my MVC ignorance is showing more and more each day.  I have a view that is bound to a Model of **[Category]** which has simply a table of categories and a link that allows you to add a **[Item]** to that category and am attempting to display that partial view (**[InsertCategoryItem]**) inside a Telerik.Window object and do an HttpPost or Ajax Post to submit the view model to the controller and have it add the **[Item]** to the database.  Is this possible?  If so, can anyone give me a stripped-down example of what the View and controller should look like?

Oh, and my project is MVC3, SqlServerCompactEdition (4.0), Telerik Extensions, Razor views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [custom toolbar template](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customtoolbar) and [grid Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax). By combining these two features you can achieve you required. If you want custom popup then you have to use custom editor template of the type of your model